# API request returns 401 on powershell but on postman 200

Tags: powershell, api, rest, postman, unauthorized

I have this request that is a carbon copy (from the chrome console, thank you google) The session is opened and the cookie is alive but for some reason on Powershell is prompting 401, however on Postman is working perfectly. I've googled it and they say that i have to encode it on base 64, i did it with the same result. I'm trying to use the Xrsf token given and the ID instead of user and password, please note that i don't have an user and password and I have to work with these tokens and IDs, please bear it in mind for possible encoding answers.

The most important headers (if i remove them the request won't go on Postman) are x-XSRF-TOKEN and the cookie where you have the ID and tokens, removing any of these will cause the request to return 401 unauthorised.

```
$id = "nsu38L1xRGS2YzYad7LwVw|pSbDDmSDd7dP836sxvwJNXwweEWTD3s7xJ5oPcYZ"
$token = "VRnWDtc6JJrSSXGFsDIGSsxaqa0SbVbkHFSFSFSFSFwxyqg3CKU"
$id = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($id)
$id = [Convert]::ToBase64String($id)
$token = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($token)
$token = [Convert]::ToBase64String($token)
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://tableauserver.am.echonet/vizportal/api/web/v1/getServerUsers" `
-Method "POST" `
-Headers @{
"sec-ch-ua"="`" Not;A Brand`";v=`"99`", `"Google Chrome`";v=`"91`", `"Chromium`";v=`"91`""
  "Accept"="application/json, text/plain, */*"
  "X-XSRF-TOKEN"="$token"
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile"="?0"
  "User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
  "Origin"="https://tableauserver.am.echonet"
  "Sec-Fetch-Site"="same-origin"
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode"="cors"
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest"="empty"
  "Referer"="https://tableauserver.am.echonet/"
  "Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
  "Accept-Language"="en-US,en;q=0.9"
  "Cookie"="persist=!9xF+uxkmcIc/PdfddsaewUU98ySpzJVE7fgdsbe+Dddsjzgdf9SfTdgNyd/UTOFu8Pgs2o4X08j/e1Kv3GCNGOmpG5Nd0WdbTM=; workgroup_session_id=$id; XSRF-TOKEN=$token"
} `
-ContentType "application/json;charset=UTF-8" `
-Body "{`"method`":`"getServerUsers`",`"params`":{`"filter`":{`"operator`":`"and`",`"clauses`":[{`"operator`":`"eq`",`"field`":`"username`",`"value`":`"423dse063`"},{`"operator`":`"eq`",`"field`":`"domainName`",`"value`":`"local`"}]},`"page`":{`"startIndex`":0,`"maxItems`":1}}}"
```

I've also tried to encode the Id and token as shown in this post:

https://qualys-secure.force.com/discussions/s/article/000003066

The command without encryption has also being tried.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Error on powershell]

Comment: Have you seen this link, the way you're building your headers are very fragile and prone to break.  Following the approach from the article, you'll build a credential object in a more stable and expected manner. https://lbk.io/post/142144850713/tableau-rest-api-powershell-quickstart

Comment: Also, the `xsrf` is an anti CORS token, you probably want your authentication to be under this key in your headers.  `$headers.Add(“X-Tableau-Auth”, $authToken)`